# why does gql query result cause exception when calling get()

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

I am attempting to retrieve an entry from my datastore with this:

```
 query = UserData.gql("WHERE mDeviceId = :1", id)
 Utils.log("my Object:" + str(query))
 entry = query.get()
```

It just so happens that the variable 'id' doesn't even exist (typo), so I know how to fix this, but I don't understand why the result I get won't let me call get() on it. When I do, I get the error:

```
Exception: Unsupported type for property  : <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

Normally I just check if entry == None to see if I get no results. Does anyone know why this occurs and if I should be doing my checks for None differently, in case I have such typos in the future?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A variable named `id` is not defined in your code, so it passes the builtin function `id`, and QL complains that it's getting a function when it expected a value (integer?).

Check to make sure you're assigning `id` a value before you use it.

Even better, don't shadow builtins with your own variables-- it'll cause confusing errors like this. :-)

Comment: ohhhh, I didn't even realize 'id' was a builtin function. I thought it was merely a mispelled variable. It threw me when my log call succeeded, implying to me that there was no problem with the gql call itself. Thanks.